# How to check Magento index status

Tags: magento

How do I get status of Magento index status. I would like to rebuild indexing programmatically if needed according to status. The following code will re-index all without considering status.

I would like to rebuild index if only required.

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
   $index->reindexAll();
}
```

Comment: I think this will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/check-if-reindexing-is-needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like that

```
$myindex = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('processcode');
echo $myindex->getStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way.

```
for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++){
    $process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessById($i);
    $state = $process->getStatus();
    if($state == Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_PENDING){
        $process->reindexEverything();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea, you don't know if there's really 9 indexes, and you don't do any checks on objects to make sure they exist